# No members available for a vector of structs

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, struct

I have a template class called *Heap*. My problem is that I want to implement the insert function at the bottom. But I can't reach the member variable of the Values vector. When I write Values[hole/2].tall it can't reach it(tall variable does not come directly after writing the dot). So can anybody please explain this ?

```
template <class Comparable>
class Heap
{
...
private:
// I have this vector
vector <heightNode <Comparable>> Values

};

template <typename Comparable>
struct heightNode
{
    Comparable tall;
    Comparable label;

    heightNode(const Comparable & t = Comparable(), const Comparable & la = Comparable()): tall(t),label(la) {}

    heightNode(const heightNode & rhs): tall(rhs.tall),label(rhs.label){}
};


template <class Comparable>
void Heap <Comparable>:: insert (const Comparable & value, const int & label)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        cout <<"Heap is Full";
    }
    else
    {
        ++currentSize;//hole is an index we will put it to the last point in the vector.
        for(int hole=currentSize; hole>1 && (value > Values[hole/2].tall)); hole/=2 )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some compile error or it is just an auto-completion IDE problem that it does not show that the member exists ("tall variable does not come directly after writing the dot")?

Comment: Actually I do not remember the error. Now I fix some of it. But before it gave me some error like it cant convert from something to something. But now it did not gave error. But it still does not auto complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
for(int hole=currentSize; hole>1 && (value > Values[hole/2].tall)); hole/=2 )
```

contains a surplus round closing bracket; make it

```
for (int hole=currentSize; hole>1 && (value > Values[hole/2].tall); hole/=2)
```

Comment: @gunescelli: What about not the "real" problem here? That is plainly a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Yes you are right. The visual studio does not show the members when a template class is in such position.